# How can I replace a space a character for two other characters in linux with tr or sed command?

Tags: regex, linux, vim, sed

I'm editing my .vimrc file to integrate vim with ranger, and I have this code:

```
fun! RangerChooser()
   exec "silent !ranger --choosefile=/tmp/chosenfile " . expand("%:p:h")
   if filereadable('/tmp/chosenfile')
      exec 'tabnew ' . system("cat /tmp/chosenfile")
      call system('rm /tmp/chosenfile')
   endif
   redraw!
endfun
```

the thing is that when I try to open a file with a path that has a folder with a name that has a space in it, it fails, because it trunk the path. I think this is because ranger doesn't use a backslash before spaces, so it is understood. This happens in the system call in the fourth line. I added some commands to insert the backslash, but I have some problems with the " ' " and the qoutes. Does anybody have a solution please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shellescape()` does all of this and more for you:

```
exec "silent !ranger --choosefile=/tmp/chosenfile " . shellescape(expand("%:p:h"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still have this error: E172: Only one file name allowed. What it could be?

Comment: @ivo: Hmm. Does it occur on that line? Does `fnameescape(shellescape(expand(…)))` work?

Comment: @minitech I don't think you want both of those at the same time. That would end up over escaping things.

Comment: @ivo which line is generating the E172? I highly doubt it is the line in minitech's answer. I bet its the line with tabnew so wrapping the system function in `fnameescape` should be sufficient.

Comment: @FDinoff THANKS! IT WORKED! :) the fnameescape had to be in the system call! Thank you!!!